# WPF MVVM - Views does not inherit the Data context from it's parent window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datacontext

I ask this question after searching though a lot of solution and none of them worked,

My problem can be resumed this way: I have a main window (MainWindow.xaml), I have a view (ParametersView.xaml).

I also have the MainViewModel.cs file that would be my DataContext common to both view.

First I would like to make the parameter view inherit the DataContext from the MainWindows view, which is MainViewModel.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Background="Transparent"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Border Background="#272537"
            CornerRadius="35">

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">

                <RadioButton Content="Acquisition"
                             Height="50"
                             Foreground="White"
                             FontFamily="Century Gothic"
                             FontSize="20"
                             Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                             />

                <RadioButton Content="Data visualization"
                             Height="50"
                             Foreground="White"
                             FontFamily="Century Gothic"
                             FontSize="20"
                             Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                             Command="{Binding DataVisuViewCommand}"/>

                <RadioButton Content="Parameter"
                             Height="50"
                             Foreground="White"
                             FontFamily="Century Gothic"
                             FontSize="20"
                             Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                             IsChecked="True"
                             Command="{Binding ParameterViewCommand}"/>

                <RadioButton Content="Post processing"
                             Height="50"
                             Foreground="White"
                             FontFamily="Century Gothic"
                             FontSize="20"
                             Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                             Command="{Binding MembersViewCommand}"/>

                <Label x:Name="fqfs" Foreground="White"/>

            </StackPanel>

            <Button x:Name="Close_b" Grid.Column="1" Width="35" Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,20,0" Style="{StaticResource PowerButton}" Click="close_a_Click"/>

            <Button x:Name="Minimize_b" Grid.Column="1" Width="35" Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,75,0" Style="{StaticResource MinimizeButton}" Click="minimize_a_Click"/>

            <local:ParametersView Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="View" />
            <!--<ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>-->

        </Grid>

    </Border>
</Window>
```

Initially, I was using ContentControl, but since the problem come from the Context, I tested with a more straightforward way, and it still doesn't work.

**ParametersView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MVVMTest.ParametersView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMTest"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">


    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Parameter"
                   Foreground="White"
                   FontSize="30"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="0,0,0,20"
                   FontFamily="Century Gothic"/>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Button x:Name="Export" Content="Save" Width="250" Height="40" Background="#01202f" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource ParameterButton}"/>
            <Button x:Name="Import" Content="Load" Width="250" Height="40" Background="#01202f" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource ParameterButton}" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
        
        </StackPanel>

        <Label x:Name="dataCOntextLabel" Foreground="White"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I tried to use the DataContext relative to the parent but it still doesn't work, I use a label (fqfs in MainWindow, and dataCOntextLabel in ParameterView) in order to view each dataContext, fqfs display what I want, but dataCOntext remain empty.

But since my view is defined as a children of the mainWindows, I should not even have to precise a DataContext in the Parameter view, yet it still doesn't work.

I precise that all the .cs file are still by default except for these two obvious line:

`fqfs.Content = this.DataContext;` (MainWindow.xaml.cs)
`dataCOntextLabel.Content = "DataContext = " + this.DataContext;` (ParametersView.xaml.cs)

MainViewModel.cs is also empty, but since I never refer to any change of view, it shouldn't have any impact.

I been though most of the question on the subject on internet and searched by myself for a while but it seems I really can't figure what is wrong here, i would really appreciate it if someone have a solution to this problem.

EDIT 1:
The reason I try this is because I need to understand how to properly set up a DataContext in a bigger project (where I also have this problem), the problem is that the project is a bit complex, so I choosed to find the solution in a new (and smaller) project before trying to implement it in the bigger project.

I need the MainWindow and the ParameterView to be able to access the same data (for instance a collection). So they both need the same dataContext.

Beside, if you have the answer for ContentControl as well (use in comment in MainWindows.xaml), it would be really helpful too as I meant to use that later for dynamic view.

Thank in advance.

**ParameterView.xaml.cs**

```
namespace MVVMTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ParametersView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ParametersView : UserControl
    {
        public ParametersView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dataCOntextLabel.Content = "DataContext = " + this.DataContext;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            View.DataContext = this;

            fqfs.Content = this.DataContext;
        }
```

Comment: The DataContext Binding in the UserControl's XAML is redundant (and actually wrong considering the possibility that there may be no Window parent). Do not set it at all. The DataContext will automatically be set by dependency property value inheritance.

Comment: Please also clarify why the UserControl's DataContext should be set *at all*. There don't seem to be any Bindings in its XAML.

Comment: I've just tried, but DataContext is still null if I do so. It's like it doesn't even know it has a parent, or it is not defined (while it clearly have a parent in MainWindow xaml). (And I tried by no setting it at all, but the result is the same)

Comment: You could use [Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) to have a look at the various controls and their data contexts in the running application.

Comment: Where do see that it is null? At a breakpoint in its constructor? That is too early, as it may be set later.

Comment: I see it in the label, I use label, and I set it up after the initialization of each view.
It work fine for MainWindow,  but is null for ParameterView. I'll take a look at snoop.

Comment: There is no Binding on the Label, so why should its DataContext be relevant?

Comment: For the `dataCOntextLabel.Content` assignment, where are you doing that? In the ParametersView constructor?

Comment: Yes, in the constructor, after the initialization, I edited the question with the file .cs of each xaml.

Comment: Move it to a Loaded event handler, e.g. like `Loaded += (s, e) => dataCOntextLabel.Content = "DataContext = " + this.DataContext;`

Comment: Or just set a Binding on the Label like `<Label Content="{Binding}" .../>`

Comment: Do you mean like {Binding DataContext}, and using OnPropertyChange ? The DataContext is null, so it shouldn't change much

Comment: I tried and it's still null, it really seems like the DataContext from the MainWindow is never inherited by the Parameter view

Comment: It is null in the constructor, but set later. You have to understand that a UserControl is not yet fully initialized in its constructor. Why would you not just try a simple Binding?

Comment: I have an error by using a simple Binding, System.InvalidOperationException, logical tree depth exceeded

Comment: Since you set the MainWindow's DataContext to itself (a Window), the following would work for example: `<Label Content="{Binding Title}"/>`.

Comment: That's where the whole problem lies, it work fine in MainWindows, the dataContext is set and it shows, however, it doesn't in ParameterView, so I can't use any Binding in ParameterView, but the label isn't that important is it ?

Comment: That is just wrong. If you avoid any explicit DataContext assignments (except one in the MainWindow), the UserControl inherits its DataContext from its parent Window, and in the UserControl's XAML you can bind to properties of the inherited DataContext object.

Comment: I do avoid any explicit assignement, the only moment I refer to dataContext is in the mainWindow, it's in the code of the question, I don't refer to it anywhere else, but the UserControl doesn't inherit, that's why I ask the question

Answer (score 0):

In `MainWindow` keep this:

```
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

Remove all other references to `DataContext`. For example, in `MainWindow()` constructor, remove everything except `InitializeComponent()`. Remove from the `UserControl.DataContext` in `ParametersView.xaml`.

Child controls always inherit the parent `DataContext`. What you must do is provide dot-prefixed paths to your relevant viewmodel properties.

Comment: I see your point, and I did retrieve any other reference to dataContext except the one in mainWindow xaml, but that's the thing, it still doesn't inherit anything anyway. What exactly do you mean by dot-prefixed point ?

Comment: What is a *dot-prefixed path*? The most simple Binding in the UserControl would just work like `"{Binding ViewModelProperty}"`:

Comment: Clemens you are right, If you want to have a more complex viewmodel object, i.e. a `MainWindowViewmodel` that has a inner property `public ParameterViewModel ParamVM {get;init;} ` you can do this to make your code properly logically separated. So in your MainWindow.xaml you would `<ParameterView DataContext="{Binding ParamVM}"/>` but you could also (in MainWindow) specify a `{Binding ParamVM.Name}` to "cherry pick" a property inside the sub-viewmodel.

Comment: Well, I understand that of course. But in the context of the question it makes no sense... I just think there is already enough confusion on the side of OP.

Comment: @Redfire said "I need the MainWindow and the ParameterView to be able to access the same data (for instance a collection). So they both need the same dataContext." True, so you would logically build a `ParameterViewmodel` with a '.Items' property and then access it from MainWindow with `{Binding ParamVM.Items}`

Comment: OP explicitly says in Edit1 he needs to set up a complex DataContext structure.